# Best practice for defining a variable on a condition in Typescript

Tags: typescript, scope

What is the best practice when you have to define a variable on a condition. The variable has the same type in both (or more) cases.

What I like to do is a ternary operator:

```typescript
const foo:string = (is_true) ? 'A' : 'B';
```

However this is not always possible. The condition might have more than 2 cases and the definition can be more complex.

So sometimes I find myself doing like so:

```typescript
let foo:string;

if(is_true){
 foo = 'A';
}else{
 foo = 'B';
}
```

or if there are more cases and the type is more complex:

```typescript
type FOO = {
  name: string
  size: number
}

let foo:FOO;

switch(is){
  case 0:{
    foo = {name: 'A', size: 0};
    break;
  }
  case 1:{
    foo = {name: 'B', size: 1};
    break;
  }
  case 2:{
    foo = {name: 'C', size: 2};
    break;
  }
}
```

Even tho I might have covered all the possibilities, I cannot be 100% sure of that.

Leaving me with an `undefined` `foo` variable. Typescript will think that the type of `foo` will be always `FOO`, but it might be of type `undefined`.

Should you always check if the variable is `undefined`?

Is there a more elegant way of doing it?

Comment: The best practice when you have to define a variable on a condition is to use a ternary operator. This will ensure that the variable is always of the correct type. If there are more than two cases, you can use a switch statement. However, you should always check if the variable is undefined before using it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to achieve this is to move your switch into a typed function with an exhaustive type check:

```
function getFoo(is: 0 | 1 | 2) {
  switch(is){
    case 0:{
      return {name: 'A', size: 0};
    }
    case 1:{
      return {name: 'B', size: 1};
    }
    case 2:{
      return {name: 'C', size: 2};
    }
    default:{
      const exhaustiveCheck: never = is;
      return exhaustiveCheck;
    }
  }
}
```

This will return an object matching the `FOO` type when a valid value is given, and error if an invalid value is given or if a valid value is missing a case.